# How to Model.fetch(<object>) when the returned data is a single object

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I want to make an API call for searching that looks like this:

```
https://myapi.com/search/<query>/<token>
```

where `query` is the search term and `token` (optional) is an alphanumeric set of characters which identifies the position of my latest batch of results, which is used for infinite scrolling.

This call returns the following JSON response:

```
{
  "meta": { ... },
  "results" {
    "token": "125fwegg3t32",
    "content": [
      {
        "id": "125125122778",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum...",
        ...
      },
      {
        "id": "125125122778",
        "text": "Dolor sit amet...",
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

`content` is an array of (embedded) items that I'm displaying as search results. My models look like this:

```
App.Content = Em.Model.extend({
  id: Em.attr(),
  text: Em.attr(),
  ...
});

App.Results = Em.Model.extend({
  token: Em.attr(),
  content: Em.hasMany('App.Content', {
    key: 'content',
    embedded: true
  })
});
```

In order to make that API call, I figured I have to do something like this:

```
App.Results.reopenClass({
  adapter: Em.RESTAdapter.create({
    findQuery: function(klass, records, params) {
      var self = this,
          url = this.buildURL(klass) + '/' + params.query;

      if (params.token) {
        url += '/' + params.token;
      }

      return this.ajax(url).then(function(data) {
        self.didFindQuery(klass, records, params, data);
        return records;
      });
    }
  }),
  url: 'https://myapi.com/search',
});
```

then somewhere in my routes do this:

```
App.Results.fetch({query: 'query', token: '12kgkj398512j'}).then(function(data) {
  // do something
  return data;
})
```

but because the API returns a single object and `Em.RESTAdapter.findQuery` expects an array, an error occurs when Ember Model tries to materialize the data. So how do I do this properly? I'm using the latest build of Ember Model.

By the way, I'm aware that it would be much more convenient if the API was designed in a way so I can just call `App.Content.fetch(<object>)`, which would return a similar JSON response, but I would then be able to set the `collectionKey` option to `content` and my data would be properly materialized.

Comment: I think you will need to override the serializer with custom code. Then you can transform the returned data to fit your needs. Either make it return a single object array with a known `id` and get the results from that, or just return only the results directly to the model. http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_creating-custom-transformations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to override your models `load()` method to adjust the payload hash to what Ember.Model wants. There are no serializers in Ember.Model.  There is both a class level load for handling collections and an instance level load for loading the JSON specific to a single model. You want to override the instance level load method to wrap the  `content` key value in an array if its not one already.

I have been using Ember.Mode quite heavily and enhanced it for a number of my use cases and submitted PR's for both fixes and enhancements.  Those PRs have been sitting there for a while with no response from the maintainers.  I have now moved to Ember.Data which has been 'rebooted' so to speak and having a lot better result with it now.

I would strongly suggest walking away from Ember.Model as it appears dead with the new pragmatic direction Ember Data has taken and because the project maintainer doesn't appear to have any interest in it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the Ember Model tip, I also noticed the project has kinda been abandoned, but I didn't know Ember Data has been reworked.